# Fixing Asterisk directory path

Tags: linux, asterisk, redhat

I have asterisk 11 installed on Centos. Everything was working fine till yesterday. I was installing mysql and using  for connection. I have it working and my cdr are now nicely posted into mysql db. But in the process of getting getting ODBC working I had to rebuild the installation and somehow created a new problem.

The path to sound files (and other stuff like agi-bin) is now screwed up. I NOW get an error that it can find  unless I specify the path.

```
exten => 200,1,Answer()
    same => n,Playback(hello-world)
    ; same => n,Playback(/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en/hello-world)
    same => n,Hangup()
```

Same problem with agi-bin:
It is trying to find files at  /usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin/CA_via_Asterisk.py
when it should be looking at /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/CA_via_Asterisk.py

asterisk.conf looks like this (which is the way it was before)

```
[directories](!)
stetcdir => /etc/asterisk
astmoddir => /usr/lib64/asterisk/modules
astvarlibdir => /var/lib/asterisk
astdbdir => /var/lib/asterisk
astkeydir => /var/lib/asterisk
astdatadir => /var/lib/asterisk
astagidir => /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin
astspooldir => /var/spool/asterisk
astrundir => /var/run/asterisk
astlogdir => /var/log/asterisk
astsbindir => /usr/sbin
```

I suppose I messed something up when I rebuilt it. But I don't know what i might have done.

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, stu

Comment: I posted it on this site as I found a several threads related to setting up Asterisk. However I will take your advice and post it on some other sites

Answer (score -1):

`(!)` - mean template. I.e by default it turned off. Remove `(!)` if you want change something

Comment: Is this related to my question??

Comment: Yes. You posted config in which you have template, but no configuration section. I.e that is same as empty file.